# How to change the path of ManyToMany by its ID

Tags: symfony4, api-platform.com

I created a Symfony project with API-Platform and I would like to change the default behavior of Api platform for ManyToMany relationships. 
By default, this one returns the path of relationships and I would like him to return his ID

I read the API-Platform doc but I didn't find anything

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"read"}}
 * })
 */

class Work
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\WorkFilter", inversedBy="works")
     * @Groups("read")
     */
    private $filters;
}
```

My current Json

```
[
  {
    "title": "Work 1",
    "filters": [
      "/api/work_filters/1",
      "/api/work_filters/2"
    ]
  }
]
```

The desired Json

```
[
  {
    "title": "Work 1",
    "filters": [
      "1",
      "2"
    ]
  }
]
```

Sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

finally I found the solution

Need to use `@groups` for select a specific field

[Link to the documentation](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#embedding-relations)

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"work"}}
 * })
 */

class Work
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("work")
     */
    private $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\WorkFilter", inversedBy="works")
     * @Groups("work")
     */
    private $filters;
}
```

```php
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation\ApiResource;

/**
 * @ApiResource(attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"work"}}
 * })
 */

class WorkFilter
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Groups("work")
     */
    private $id;
}
```

```
[
  {
    "title": "Work 1",
    "filters": [
      {
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```